# How do I decrypt files on SD card that I encrypted on a different device?

Tags: encryption

I encrypted my phone and SD card on my Note 2. I broke that phone, but recovered the SD card. How do I decrypt the SD card to get all files out (I do have password for it) with the new phone?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the same question that you can find at [How can I decrypt an encrypted SD card (HTC Evo 4G) on a different device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34647/how-can-i-decrypt-an-encrypted-sd-card-htc-evo-4g-on-a-different-device) - In summary of that answer, you can't. Your password only decrypts the key that is used to decrypt your files. The key is stored on the device and is NOT the same as your password.

Answer (score -1):

Encryption involves two parts:

1. Mechanism to generate key and storing it.
2. Actual encryption method.

Now both of these might differ from OEM to OEM based on their implementation. Remember Android AOSP does not support external sdcard encryption.

Now to answer your question:

If your new device is having the same firmware from same OEM, in this case Samsung and you are using a new Note 2, then there is a possibility of decrypting the sdcard with the same pin, provided mechanism to generate encryption key is same. However in case the PIN that you enter is just used to encrypt the encryption key and encryption key is generated through some other mechanism then your sdcard is as good as useless now. But it is worth giving a shot.

Comment: That won't work, unfortunately. The PIN isn't used to encrypt the data, it's merely used to encrypt the key USED to encrypt the data. This way when a user changes their PIN it isn't necessary to re-encrypt the entire block storage device; only the key needs to be decrypted and re-encrypted. The key itself is randomly generated at first boot.